# Assigning value to unintialized pointer BEFORE dereferencing

Tags: c, pointers, dereference, memory-access

I found a code snippet where a char pointer (say *pData) is declared without being initialized to NULL.

```
char *pData, *pData2;
char string[10] =  "Hello"
pData2 = &string[0];
SomeFuntionToAssignValue(pData2, &pData);

SomeFuntionToAssignValue(char *pData2, char **pData)
{
    if (something)
    {
        *pData = pData2;
    }
    else if (something)
    {
        *pData = &pData2[some calculation]
    }
}
```

Can dereferencing pData, after calling function SomeFuntionToAssignValue(), at any point of time throw a "memory access exception" error?

Because during compilation or local-testing(here testing is done in targets which can be reloaded at any point of time so usually the chances of memory corruption decreases) we didn't face any "memory access exception" error.

But during testing in the field environment, where the target was not reloaded for at least a week's time, a "memory access exception" error was thrown.

So, is there any chance that NOT doing `char *pData = NULL` could have caused the "memory access exception" error?

Comment: C doesn't have "memory access exceptions" unless you specify a platform, architecture and compiler.

Comment: Calling your function the way you show it, it will be safe to use `pData` after the call.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - Safe if `some calculation` give result in range [0,strlen(pData2)]

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya platform would be Linux and I guess it is gcc compiler. But I did get a memory access exception error which I need to fix.

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky : yeah , the range is taken care of. strlen(pData) is used along the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a chance, because your `SomeFuntionToAssignValue` doesn't *always* assign to `*pData`.  And initializing `pData` to be null *could* prevent a problem because other code *might* be checking for `NULL` but can't check for its uninitialized value.  But that all depends on code you haven't shown; there's nothing wrong with this pattern in general.